# How to use scipy optimize with your own function?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, prediction

I have scores from 3 different metrics that I combine into one weight, and I want to use scipy's optimize to determine the optimal coefficients for the weights when combining (rather than treating them all equally and taking the average, which is what I was doing before). The CV function shown in the code below deals with implementing cross validation and computing the predictions for the reactions (where a reaction is only "like" or "dislike").

```
weight = A*(metric1) + B*(metric2) + C*(metric3)
prediction = CV(post, reaction, weight)
```

I want to maximize my `accuracy`, or minimize `1 - accuracy`, where `accuracy = accuracy_score(reaction, prediction)`. I looked at the documentation for scipy's optimize/minimize and while I understand the general idea, I am not sure how to translate my ideas into actual code. For example, one area of confusion is that I want to minimize '1-accuracy', but accuracy is determined by the previous part that deals with predictions. Any help would be greatly appreciated and as always, code would be super helpful :)

Comment: (1) It it's current form this question looks more like a problem concerning your CV implementation than scipy (2) It's somewhat concealed how you are doing CV and how to use it here, but your optimization must never be done on the validation-set, only on the training-set or CV defeat's it's purpose. So it's again highly dependent on your CV-procedure. (3) I'm not sure if optimizing for accuracy is easy. Without more analysis i don't think it fits into the continuous convex opt-case (not much in scipy for discrete-opt).(4) Using accuracy with this form of weighting sounds wrong(needs thresholds

Comment: What's the one value that you want to minimize (i.e. the cost), and what variable (it may be an array (1d?))?  All other parameters to the function are `args`.  The `minimize` is vary the `x` values until it minimizes the cost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you would want to do something like in the following pseudo-code:

```
def loss(x, *args):
    A, B, C = x
    weight = A*metric1 + B*metric2 + C*metric3
    prediction = CV(post, reaction, weight)
    return -accuracy_score(reaction, prediction)
# equal initial weighting
x0 = [1, 1, 1]
scipy.optimize.minimize(loss, x0, args=args)
```

Basically the loss function that you are minimizing should take the parameters that you are optimizing over (here: the weights) and give back a scalar measure of how good they are (here: minus the accuracy score). So all the computation necessary to determine the loss that depends on the parameters should be within the loss function. If there is some part of the calculation that does not depend on the weights, you might of course speed up things by precalculating it outside the function.